# How to retrieve more than 100 videos?

Tags: dailymotion-api

I am trying to get the uploaded videos of a user but it seems that it is not possible to retrieve more than 1000 videos although more were uploaded.
An example would be this user where 
`https://api.dailymotion.com/user/Zoomin_Deutschland?fields=videos_total` returns

```
{
  "videos_total": 2067
}
```

With a query like
`https://api.dailymotion.com/user/Zoomin_Deutschland/videos?limit=100&page=9`
it still works starting with:

```
{"page":9,"limit":100,"explicit":false,"has_more":true,"list":[{ <...>
```

On page 10 it gets interesting because it states that there are no more results to fetch:

```
{"page":10,"limit":100,"explicit":false,"has_more":false,"list":[{ <...>
```

On page 11 no results are returned:

```
{"page":11,"limit":100,"explicit":false,"total":0,"has_more":false,"list":[]}
```

How is it possible to retrieve information about the remaining videos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although not documented, it's possible DailyMotion has a soft search limit of 1000 items (YouTube's soft limit is 500).

To get all videos, you can loop requests using the *created_after* and *created_before* filters going back every month or year at a time (assuming each request is < 1000 items) in order to get them all.

Comment: Ingenious! Thank you very much for this suggestion. It is more hassle than I would like but it works.
The downside is that you don't know how many videos are returned in the given timeframe and if I get exactly 1000 back I split the timeframe in half and retry recursively. Sadly, this wastes the 10 previous requests in this case (since I can't be sure which videos were left out).